# How do you evaluate ML model already deployed in production?

Tags: deployment, machine-learning

so to be more clear lets consider the problem of loan default prediction.
Let's say I have trained and tested off-line multiple classifiers and ensembled them. Then I gave this model to production.

But because people change, data and many other factors change as well. And performance of our model eventually will decrease. So then it needs to be replaced with the new, better model.

What are the common techniques, model stability tests, model performance tests, metrics after deployment? How to decide when to replace current model with newer one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend wich problem (classification, regression or clustering), let say you have a classification problem and you learned and tested a model with 75% of accuracy (or other metric) , once in production, if the accuracy is  **Significantly** less than 75% , than you can stope your model and see what is happening.

In my case, I note the accuracy of the model once in production each day for a week, after that I count a mean and a variance of accuracy and I apply a T-test of mean, to see if this accuracy is  Significantly diverge or not from the  accuracy desired.

Hope that will help